# Configure dynamic file name for server log file in Intellij Idea 14.0.3

Tags: regex, logging, intellij-idea

For Intellij Idea 14.0.3, I have to daily change my log file location because I maintain different log files for my tomcat for each day. So for eg, 2 March 2015 log file name would be log20150302 and for 3rd Dec 2014 it would be log20141203, basically in logYYYYMMDD format. How can I configure this type of file name in my log location through a regex/something else, so that I don't have to change the file name manually on everyday basis. Please find below ,screenshot for the exact location of this configuration.

[image: Setting log file location in Intellij Idea for running server]

Comment: If the log name supports parameter expansion (as in BASH) you can try log$(date +"%Y%m%d")

Comment: Thanks @MBarnett , unfortunately, this doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Got the following response from Jetbrains Support, tried and it looks the correct solution to me:

> In Log file location text box you can specify a pattern, like
>   /path/to/folder/log* and to select whether to display all files
>   covered by this pattern or only the last changed file, by
>   enabling/disabling Show all files covered by pattern option
>   https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/setting-log-options.html .
>
> JetBrains, Inc  http://www.jetbrains.com  "Develop with pleasure!"

Comment: Didn't work for me. Can you please explain more how you solved it?